# Should we use getPath or getAbsolutePath in Android

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

When working with files in Android system, should we use `File` `getPath` or `getAbsolutePath`?

For example we downloaded file, then we use `DownloadManager.addCompletedDownload()` to add this file to global `downloads` folder to be available there, which `path` we should pass?

Another example when we create `File` inside `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()` folder, `getPath` or `getAbsolutePath`?

And last example when we use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android, it is a common practice not to rely on `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. At any rate, when the **zigote** starts your app, this is set to `/`, and there is only one filesystem, so for all practical purposes, `File.getPath()` and `File.getAbsolutePath()` will produce identical results.

But if you are *going for the style points*, you are expected to use absolute paths when your process communicates to other processes, including system services. Therefore talking to **DownloadManager** or to **MediaScanner**, you will better express you intent by using `getAbsolutePath()`. On the other hand, for in-app file paths, e.g. `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` to find and read a file, `getPath()` will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager#addCompletedDownload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean))

> path: String: absolute pathname to the file.

So, I guess you should pass the absolute path. However, note that `DownloadManager.addCompletedDownload()` was deprecated on Android Q

On Android Q, they introduced the Scoped Storage concept and that had a huge impact in how you access files. I think you can get more info from [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)

So, I strongly recommend to test and consider Android Q devices in your implementation.

Comment: I have updated my question, `addCompletedDownload()` indeed specify absolute path, but `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` not , on which method we should relay globally?